# how to set up ubuntu in an empty partition i created on my laptop hd

Tags: installation, partitioning

I took 50 gigs of space and partitioned it off in windows. I then removed rights from any user with access to the computer as it is part of a domain. I'm not pc literate enough to know exactly which options to select in order to install ubuntu into the partition. I do not know which selections to make for the otions that are shown on the partition window during the installation process. If anyone could inform me how to correctly do this it would be much appreciated
!

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is the full guide to a correct installation https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation

Try to read big lines and reply here for more specific things you may ask about.

Also, mind checking out some FAQ on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) and on the [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org)